# make jlabel with dynamic variable

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

guys how to make dynamic parameter.i want to make a new JLabel with dynamic variable.my variable is from jtextfield gettext.but when i try in netbeans.it's error.i can't make this dynamic like my script.how to make my variable is dynamic?

```
JLabel jTextField1.getText() = new JLabel;
```

Comment: follow a basic Swing tutorial, and you will know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JLabel.setText to accomplish your goal. Here is a demo to modify the label dynamically. Hope it helps.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main{

    private JFrame frame;
    JLabel label = new JLabel("LABEL");
    JTextField field = new JTextField(10);

    public void initialWindow(){
        frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Main mainObj = new Main();
                mainObj.initialWindow();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    class MainPanel extends JPanel{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        public MainPanel(){
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            add(field, BorderLayout.WEST);
            button.addActionListener(new MyListener());
            add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(label, BorderLayout.EAST);
        }
    }

    class MyListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            label.setText(field.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the effect:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's only set text.not parameter like what i mean sir?o_oa...i jut want to declare name of jlabel from my jtextfield gettext

Comment: @FRIDY "*it's only set text.not parameter like what i mean sir?*" - You probably mean the **variable**, not the parameter. Basic concept to show you: `Class variable = new Class(parameter1, parameter2)`. And no, I don't think it's possible to make a variable completely dynamic. The closest you can get would probably be a Map or an Array.

Comment: ok...but in netbeans it's call parameter >.<a not variable but thx

Answer (score 2):

```
JLabel textFieldLabel = new JLabel (jTextField1.getText ());
```

Comment: it's only set text.not parameter like what i mean sir?o_oa...i jut want to declare name of jlabel from my jtextfield gettext

Comment: it's ilegall forward reference